# what is the meaning of "mutable state" in react forms or generally

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am reading about **Controlled components** in reactjs docs, I paused the reading because them mention a term unknow for me:

> In HTML, form elements such as `<input>, <textarea>, and <select>` typically maintain their own state and update it based on user input. In React, **mutable state** is typically kept in the state property of components, and only updated with setState().

Referrer to **mutable state**, anybody could show me an example or a description more easy to understand

Comment: Is it the meaning of the word "mutable" that you are interested in?

Comment: mutable in the context of forms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Mutable" in programming refers to anything that can change during the running of a program. The [dictionary definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mutable) is "liable or subject to change or alteration".

The opposite would be "[Immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)" (i.e. something that cannot change). In the context of a React component, this would be the `props`.

So in the context of a form, the *mutable state* would be made up of the contents of the inputs that make up the form. (Unless of course you set one of those inputs to be read only!)